# Facebook Insights API and FQL: retrieving the page_active_users_city metric WITH the state

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-insights

We're pulling down the list of top 20 active user cities for our Page using the following FQL query:

```sql
SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=MY_PAGE_ID AND metric='page_fans_city' AND end_time=end_time_date('2011-09-07') AND period=period('lifetime')
```

The problem is the data returned only returns the city name and the fan count. There's no state defined in the data returned; so when the query returns Louisville with a count of 12345; there's no way for me to tell if it's Louisville,KY; Louisville, CO; or some other city that happens to be named Louisville.

Is there anyway to retrieve the state and/or zip in addition to the city and count from the query above? Or is there maybe an alternative way I can get the number of users and active users for my page that will include both the top cities with states and user counts?

Any constructive input is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talked to a company contact in Facebook's dev team; they looked into it for me. Unfortunately, they confirmed that the state/region information isn't currently available in Insights and won't be for the foreseeable future.